# Nservicebus NHibernate Azure Subscription Storage Exception

Tags: azure, nservicebus, azure-storage

when I try to run the Azure sample, I get the following error from the

OrderService:

```
Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: No

configuration section for NHibernate Azure Subscription Storage found. Please

add a NHibernateAzureSubscriptionStorageConfig section to you configuration

file.
```

I wonder why this happens, because from what I know NHibernate is not used for

Azure queues?

These question was also [asked here](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/messages/11423?threaded=1&m=e&var=1&tidx=1) But no response has been given. 
Anyone with ideas

Comment: NHibernate is used to store subscriptions in table storage. what happens if you add the config? (look at the samples that comes with nsb for exact syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i finally was able to sort out the error by going through the samples again. I guess i had some settings messing from the config files. But thanks to the response @Andreas Öhlund